# Is Not Equal in linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq in my project.

I want all teachers from viewTeachers where Mailcode is not equal to 20.

My code is

```
var startWithFullName = from v in Db.viewTeachers
                                            where v.FullName.StartsWith(prefix) && !v.MailCode.Equals(20)
                                            orderby v.FullName
                                            select new { v.ID, v.FullName };

                    foreach (var teacher in startWithFullName)
                    {
                        teacherTable.Rows.Add(teacher.FullName, teacher.ID);
                    }
```

I have written

```
!v.MailCode.Equals(20)
```

But not sure its correct on not.

Can any one tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Your problem must be elsewhere. Are using EF Code First? Then in the debugger you should see the generated SQL statement. Is it what you expect? (maybe try it directly on the DB).

Comment: @ igor  Yes Mailcode type is int.

Comment: @ jeroenh I have executed the queries directly in DB. it works perfectly but in aspx page it is not executing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply write your condition as:

```
v.MailCode != 20
```

So your where clause should be:

```
where v.FullName.StartsWith(prefix) && v.MailCode != 20
```

Comment: @HiralBavisi, do you have records with MailCode 20 and and Name starting with your prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The condition can be written as `!= 20`..

Something like this :

```
var startWithFullName = from v in Db.viewTeachers 
          where v.FullName.StartsWith(prefix) && v.MailCode != 20
          orderby v.FullName 
          select new 
              { 
                 v.ID, 
                 v.FullName 
               };
```

Comment: Not working. It doesnt show me any error but it also doesnot showing any teacher.

Answer (score -1):

It will not compile. Equals use in joins and in where condition you should use  !=.
Hope this will clear your doubts.

Comment: compiles perfectly fine. He's not talking about `equals` operator but `Equals` method